# React JS Render CPU usage on screen

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to render on screen the current CPU usage within a react-js application?

I've found node js examples however, none with react.

Node example packages:

https://github.com/oscmejia/os-utils

Comment: I don't think react can do something like that, since it's just a framework and not a runtime environment like node which has access to the said machine to calculate the CPU usage.

Comment: dep on your js runtime. browser runtime obviously have no access to CPU info. if you run react in electron of course you can do that.

Comment: There is a way to check it in Node.js and request it in Javascript/ React

Comment: @AfiaUdofia it will return the server's CPU usage, i thinks Filth is looking for client side device metrics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your computers cores with browser api. You need a backend language to accomplish this. Nodejs comes with a built in OS module that allows you to do this. So I suggest to learn how to build a simple node server and deploy it with something like heroku.